# Parse text from HTML form inside table cell with Cheerio

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, html-table, cheerio

I have a HTML table that looks like this:

```
<tr class="row-class" role="row">
    <td>Text1</td>
    <td>
        <form method='get' action='http://example.php'> 

            <input type='hidden' name='id_num' value='ABCD123'> <!-- < I NEED THIS VALUE -->

            <button type='submit' class='btn' title='Check' ></button> 
        </form>
    </td>  
</tr>
```

**I want to get the value of the hidden input type named `id_num`.** (In this example the value I want is *"ABCD123"*).

I tried to parse the code with [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) like this:

```
var $ = cheerio.load(body);
$('tr').each(function(i, tr){
    var children = $(this).children();

    var x       = children.eq(0);
    var id_num  = children.eq(1);

    var row = {
        "x":        x.text().trim(),     //this is correct, value is Text1
        "id_num":   id_num.text().trim() //This is empty, value is "", I want the value "ABCD123"
    };
});
```

But I only get the first value correct.

**How can I get the value from the hidden input element `id_num`?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `eq(1)` was getting the whole `<tr>`, try this instead:

```
$('tr').each(function(i, tr){
      var children = $(this).children('td');
      var x        = $(children[0]);
      var id_num   = $(children[1]).find("input[name='id_num']");
      var row = {
          "x":        x.text(),
          "id_num":   id_num.val()
      };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That should be:

```
$(tr).find('[name="id_num"]').attr('value')
```

Comment: This solution is 100% correct, thank you! I chose the other one as the answer because it's more similar to the code I previously written.

Comment: It's unnecessarily messy though. Don't mess around with `children` when you can get what you  need easily with css.